# Linq add condition to all fields

Tags: vb.net, linq

LINQ and VB.NET

I will like to put the search condition to all fields in Table.
Example:

```
Dim query = From c in dbContext.MyTable 
      Where c.Field1 = "searchString" or c.Field2 = "searchString" or _
      c.Field3 = "searchString" or …
      Select c
```

Assume that I have more then 100 fields and more tables. I will like to write something like this:

```
Dim query = From c in in dbContext.MyTable
     Where Search(c)
     Select c

Private Sub Search(c …??)
    dim cond as string  
    for each field in c
        cond += field.name = "searchstring"
    next
    return cond
End sub
```

If this is dynamic linq could you post me the solution (VB.NET) and example and …
I already look in https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/ for System.Linq.Dynamic but there is no example and no suggestion which solution is best. Does have Microsoft solution for this? What is the best approach?

Thanks. Best regards.

**ADDED**

This code works for string and text type. **How would I add a solution for int and DateTime type??** For integer must be exact number field = 123 and will not show when field is 1234 or 112345.

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic

  Dim dbContext As New DevicesLINQDataContext
  Dim columnNames = dbContext.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(GetType(DevicesLINQDataContext)).GetMetaType(GetType(VDevices)).DataMembers

  Dim Condition As New StringBuilder
  For Each col In columnNames
      If col.DbType.Contains("char") Then
          Condition.Append(col.Name & ".Contains(@0)").Append(" OR ")
      End If
      If IsNumeric(txtSearch.Text) Then
          If col.DbType.Contains("int") Then
             Condition.Append(col.Name & " = " & CInt(txtSearch.Text)).Append(" OR ")
          End If
      End If
      If col.DbType.Contains("date") Then
          Condition.Append(col.Name & ".Contains(@0)").Append(" OR ") ' Not working????
      End If
  Next
  If Condition.Length > 0 Then
      Condition.Length = Condition.Length - 3 ' removing last OR
      query = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(query, Condition.ToString, txtSearch.Text)
  End If
```

**ADDED 2:**
For type DateTime or Date I made the next solution:

```
If col.DbType.ToLower.Contains("date") then
    If IsDate(txtSearch.Text) And Not txtSearch.Text.Contains(":") Then 
        Condition.Append(col.Name & " > DateTime(" & CDate(txtSearch.Text).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy, M, d") & ")").Append(" AND ")
        Condition.Append(col.Name & " < DateTime(" & CDate(txtSearch.Text).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy, M, d") & ")").Append(" OR ") 
    End If
End if
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify one thing. Are the fields of the table you're querying changing or is the table design fixed?

Comment: Table design is fixed, but it will be more tables. This will be one general approach for all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the linq (pardon the pun).... that I used to get familiar with linq.dynamic but there are others.... search for linq.dynamic

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

**UPDATE**

```
Dim WhereBuild As New StringBuilder
Dim mySearchString as String = "FindMe"

For Each field In c
    WhereBuild.Append(field.Name).Append(" = """).Append(mySearchString).Append(""" OR ")
Next
'Remove last  'OR'
WhereBuild.Remove(WhereBuild.Length-3, 3)


'Build query
Dim dc as New myDataContext

Dim AList = dc.MyTable _
            .Where(WhereBuild.ToString) _
            .OrderBy(ddl_SortBy.SelectedValue)

'Here I bind my results to a gridview
myGridView.DataSource = AList
myGridView.DataBind()
```

.OrderBy(ddl_SortBy.SelectedValue) is optional. ddl_SortBy would contain the field names as values.
*Type from scratch not tested.

Comment: I already read this and more. This is .Net 3.5 version (2008), I have .Net 4.5.1. Is it supported from Microsoft? Can I get the solution for my problem in VB?
Thanks.

Comment: Im using Linq.Dynamic with .net4 and 4.5 with no issues. I'll post a solution I use.

Comment: @user2214999 please see example posted... I've amended my code to take your for next loop of fields and build a Where Clause... I've not had chance to test.

Comment: Work as long as the fields are text type. If there's a date or int type then report an error: "Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'String'"
How I can solve the problem of the conversion of all fields in the string. Dynamic Linq does not recognize DateTimeField.ToString.Contains("2011").
Thanks

Comment: In that case you will need to change the way the Where clause is built up to take into account the different field types.

Comment: I've added above code that works for string. Could you please added the solution for integer and date?

Comment: Do you want it to equal a specific date or just a date part

Comment: Date part. For specific date I created this: Case col.DbType.ToLower.Contains("date")  
If IsDate(IskaniNiz) And Not IskaniNiz.Contains(":") Then                                   Condition.Append(col.Name & " > DateTime(" & CDate(IskaniNiz).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy, M, d") & ")").Append(" AND ").Append(col.Name & " < DateTime(" & CDate(IskaniNiz).AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy, M, d") & ")").Append(" OR ") 
End If

Comment: OK... you have almost cracked it... For datepart which part are you searching (year?)... I think you will need to include this in with the IsNumeric check. if txtSearch.Text is an acceptable 'Year' then construct a date (startofYear) of 01/01/txtSearch.Text and another (endofYear) of 31/12/txtSearch.Text then use similar code and condition would be if date is >= startofYear and date <= endofYear.